# Gradle using build-file over http

Tags: gradle

In Gradle is it possible to build project using a remote build file?

E.g.:

```
gradle -b https://my.remote.server.com/build.gradle
```

The main reason I am looking for this is we can have a generic gradle file shared which has gradle-templates plugin and let the team quickly construct a gradle project for a web app or java library.

**Update based on few comments received :**

Adding some more context, today we are doing this for new engineers joining our team (interns, jr. developers, lateral hires etc.,)

```
curl -o build.gradle https://my.remote.server.com/build.gradle
gradle clean build
```

1. I am looking for solutions to combine above two lines to one. The apply pattern doesn't solve this problem.
2. Also combining into one gives some help to Windows users. Else they need to install curl before running this.

Comment: Theoretically yes (CL recognizes the URL when passed) but it doesn't work - it fails to download file, even if it's present. What You can to is that You can `apply from:` a remote file in a build script.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I didn't know. The main reason I am looking for this is we can have a generic gradle file shared which has [gradle-templates](https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-templates) plugin and let the team quickly construct a gradle project for a web app or java library.

Comment: It would be better to frame the question in terms of this use case, as there might be other solutions besides `-b` (which doesn't support HTTP URLs).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thanks for the suggestion. I just did that.

Comment: So you use curl to download a build script template that subsequently gets checked in to source control?

Comment: The second step will prompt me for : Project Name, Group Name. Once I enter those, it will create a java project with given project name & group. I move the newly created project folder to another folder and check it into source control. This is the flow for a developer who wants to use  my template to create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

`-b` is mostly meant to be used for experimentation (not so much for production), and doesn't support HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

According to Your comment it seems to be possible. Just add the following line at the beginning of the script:

```
apply from: 'http://example.com/generic.gradle'
```

And the logic defined in this script will be accessible in the script where it's applied. Of course it will working a bit slower (fetching the script over the web).

Comment: I have updated my question. "apply" doesn't minimize the no. of steps in my script, though it is a good suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "apply" doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Ok. As far as I see there's no *perfect* solution to this problem. You need to clone to project from some destination and then this build.gradle file needs to apply from remote script. I don't know how You can eliminate either of the steps.